# Cannot validate XML/XSD using Regular expression with Following expression

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

My Input Field should not accept the word "County" with all possiblities and can acccept any input string except "County". My Regular expression is defined as

```
<xs:pattern value=" (\s*)(?!county|COUNTY|County)([a-zA-Z]+)(\s*)"/>
```

While Valdiating I am getting error in the regular expression

```
<xs:pattern value=" (\s*)(?!county|COUNTY|County)([a-zA-Z]+)(\s*)"/>
```

#### Test

```
Valid string : Fairfax parkway 
Invalid String: Fairfax county
```

Comment: <xs:pattern value="(\s*)(?!county|COUNTY|County)([a-zA-Z]+)(\s*)"/>

Comment: I'm using Altova trial version- While validating with your code I got an error at symbol "?" .

Comment: Does the Software needs an extra librabries using these kind of symbols. when I removed symbol "?" in the expression XSD got validated but XML has error in that field.

Comment: Thank you Emma for the response.